# Custom ESLint rule for multiple imports

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint, eslint-rule-schema

I have `Library A` and `Library B`. I am trying to make a custom ESLint warning, so that `Library A` shows a deprecated message BUT ONLY in the instance that `Library B` is also present in the file.

```
module.exports = {
  meta: {
    messages: {
      useComponent: 'Do not use these two imports together',
    },
  },
  create(context) {
    return {
      ImportDeclaration(node) {
        if (node.source.value.includes(`Library A`)) {
          // How to check for the two imports occurring together?
          // I only want to add this message if Library B is also included
          context.report({
            node,
            messageId: 'useComponent',
          });
        }
      },
    };
  },
};
```

I've tried `context.getText(), context.source.getText(), etc`. Every variation I can find to try, but those all end up as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would collect the relevant import nodes first, and check at the end of the file if any invalid combination is used.

To do so, you can use state variables inside `create`. Variables declared in the `create` function of a rule have the scope of a file being linted - because `create` is called once for each file - so they can be used to keep track of things like a list of nodes to be used later on, or whether a particular import has been found.

```js
    create(context) {
      let importsLibA = false;
      let importsLibB = false;
      const importNodes = [];
      ...
```

To run some logic at the end of a file, the preferred approach is using the `Program:exit` selector. For context, `Program` is the topmost node of any file that contains all other nodes, and `:exit` is ESLint-specific syntax to specify a selector that runs when exiting a node - and not when entering. This is documented in the docs page about [selectors](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/selectors).

Putting it together, you should get a `create` function that looks more or less like this:

```js
create(context) {
  let importsLibA = false;
  let importsLibB = false;
  const importNodes = [];
  return {
    ImportDeclaration(node) {
      if (node.source.value.includes(`Library A`)) {
        importsLibA = true;
        importNodes.push(node);
      } else if (node.source.value.includes(`Library B`)) {
        importsLibB = true;
        importNodes.push(node);
      }
    },
    'Program:exit'() {
      if (importsLibA && importsLibB) {
        for (const node of importNodes) {
          context.report({
            node,
            messageId: 'useComponent',
          });
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```